# DP83848 doesn't appear in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, ethernet, rmii

I am studying the RMII protocol with Ethernet connection on STM32H753ZIT6. I am using the STM32CubeIDE for the configuration but there is a problem: In "LWIP" -> "Platform Settings" -> "Driver_PHY", I can't find the DP838484 as a choice for PHY device.
Does anyone know how I can get the DP83848 in the list?

Edit:

I have connected all the STM32H753ZIT6's pins to the DP83848 (follow the RMII configuration), the problem is when I enable option "LWIP" on STM32CubeIDE, in "Platform Settings" only the LAN8742 is as a device PHY available.  I need the DP83848 but I don't know how to get it in the list.

Comment: It's not clear what help you need. Please change the question "can anyone help" as it can simply be answered with "yes but what help you need".

Comment: What options do you have for a phy and why do you expect to have a dp838484? Is it used on one of ST’s dev boards?

Comment: I have connected all the STM32H753ZIT6's pins to DP83848 (follow the RMII configuration), the problem is when I enable option "LWIP" on STM32CubeIDE, in "Platform Settings" it only appear LAN8742 as a device PHY available (i need DP83848 but i dont know how to appear it)

Comment: How do you know or expect that DP83848 PHY should be there in the list? Maybe it shouldn't?

Comment: Hello again, it is because this type of microprocessor (STM32H753ZIT6) has been used with DP83848 before and worked perfectly fine and since i replace it with the new one (same STM32H7..). I supposed that through the configuration on STM32cubeIde, i could find the option PHY DP83848..

Comment: Hello, in case anyone have the same problem, theres an user who find an interesting way to add DP83848 directly in the "ethernetif" class : (https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000W54SjSAJ/the-ridiculous-way-to-run-dp83848-with-stm32h7-its-work-)